# Proof of L'Hospital's Rule, Part 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

So I was watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHvYlrud8j8&ab_channel=AndrewMcCrady and along the proof it says that $(L-\epsilon)(1-\frac{g(c)}{g(\alpha)}) + \frac{f(c)}{g(\alpha)} \lt \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \lt (L + \epsilon)(1 - \frac{g(c)}{g(\alpha)}) + \frac{f(c)}{g(\alpha)}$ implies that
$(L-\epsilon)(1-\delta) - \delta \lt \frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)} \lt (L + \epsilon) + \delta$ since $0 \lt \frac{g(c)}{g(\alpha)} \lt \delta$ and $\frac{|f(c)|}{g(\alpha)} \lt \delta$.

I understand that $0 \lt \frac{g(c)}{g(\alpha)} \lt \delta$ means that $0 \lt 1 - \delta \lt 1 - \frac{g(c)}{g(\alpha)} \lt 1$, but shouldn't the implication require that $L - \epsilon \gt 0$ for it to work? In this case, it is assuming that $L \gt 0$ is real and that $\epsilon \gt 0$ is arbitrary. So in some cases $L - \epsilon \lt 0$. Can someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: Wlog $\epsilon<L$. When you fix some $\epsilon>0$ in an epsilon-delta proof, you may restrict to small $\epsilon$s. Iff you succed in making your quantity smaller than those, it will be smaller than bigger ones.

Comment: I prefer [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof).

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks.